# Render html files with EJS with angular in it

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, ejs

I have a node + angular project. I want to render a html page and init it with some values. I wan thoses values to be linked  to the Angular scope.

So i have an input, I linked it with ng-model but this erase the EJS initialisation.

server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/front/views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use('/front',express.static(__dirname + '/front'));

app.get('/signup',function(req,res){
    res.render('view',{
        user:{
            email:"user mail",
        }
    })
});
var port = 5000;
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

view.html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="/front/controllers/app.js"></script>

<html ng-app="onboardingApp">

    <form id="msform" novalidate ng-controller="onboardingController">

        <input required  type="text" name="email" ng-model="signup.user.email">
        <label for="email">Email</label>

        <input type="button" name="next" ng-click="displaySignup()" value="NEXT"/>

    </form>

</html>
```

app.js:

```
var onboardingApp = angular.module('onboardingApp', []);

onboardingApp.controller('onboardingController',function OnboardingController($scope) {

    $scope.signup = {
        user:{
            email:""
        }
    }

    $scope.displaySignup = function(){
        console.log($scope.signup)
    }

});
```

So I am trying to set the value of: `input required  type="text" name="email" ng-model="signup.user.email"`

with ejs and then that this value to be linked with the angular model `signup.user.email.`

Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add this piece of js at the end of your view.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      angular.module('onboardingApp')
        .value('userEmail', <%- JSON.stringify(user.email) %>);
</script>
```

and then inject the component wherever you need it like so:

```
onboardingApp.controller('onboardingController',
 function OnboardingController($scope, userEmail) {

    $scope.signup = {
        user:{
            email: userEmail
        }
    }

    $scope.displaySignup = function(){
        console.log($scope.signup)
    }

});
```